# I don't understand why using the pop() function (JavaScript) on variable A to define variable B affects the value of variable A

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

### The problem

```
const threeArr = [1, 4, 6];
const oneDown = threeArr.pop();
console.log(oneDown);
console.log(threeArr);
```

The first `console.log` will produce the element `6`, which makes sense to me as the variable `oneDown` takes the last element in the array and produces it (6).

However, I don't get why the second `console.log` produces `[1, 4]`. I would expect it to produce `[1, 4, 6]` because we have not modified the variable `threeArr`.

We have modified `threeArr` for the purposes of defining `oneDown`, but I didn't think this would have an impact on the value of `threeArr` itself?

### Attempting to understand this with a simpler example

My initial thought was that this is a fundamental property of how JS works; if I define variable B to be a modification of variable A, then in that process I change the value of variable A.

I decided to test this by using a simplified example:

```
const threeArr = 1 + 2;
const oneDown = threeArr + 1;
console.log(threeArr);
console.log(oneDown);
```

However, this works as expected (the first `console.log` produces the value `3` (i.e. the value of `threeArr` has *not* been modified), and the second produces the value `4`, rather than what happens with the `pop` example).

Source: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/manipulate-arrays-with-pop

Comment: _"because we have not modified the variable threeArr"_ - yes, you did - because that is simply how `pop` works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop: _"The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array."_

Comment: Where did you learn that `pop` *doesn't* change the array?

Comment: _"Source:"_ - says it right there already, _"Another way to **change the data in an array** is with the .pop() function."_, _"In other words, .pop() **removes the last element from an array** and returns that element."_

Comment: Thanks both. I just thought that `pop` would just alter the `oneDown` array and leave `threeArr` untouched.

Comment: _"would just alter the oneDown array"_ - `oneDown` isn't even an _array_.

Comment: Why would it not be? My thought process is that since `threeArr` is an array, and `oneDown` is equal to an array and a function (a function of an array?), then `oneDown` itself would be an array?

Comment: The pop() method simply returns the last element of the array. In your case, oneDown is a number. I can only advise you to review the fundamentals

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

**The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.**

Comment: Thank you. I just thought that pop would just alter the `oneDown` array and leave `threeArr` untouched (and that `oneDown` itself would be an array because it is equal to an array and a function? Isn't that a function of an array?).

Comment: The ```pop()``` method simply returns the last element of the array. In your case, ```oneDown``` is a number